# I want to set checkbox to checked if the value comes true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using the Ant design tree component what my task is am a getting data from the backend in this tree structure and in children data I am getting key checked with the value true and false so I need to set checked if the checked key value is true if come false than not checked so checkbox will be checked by default if children data checked value is true you can also check codeSandBox link below.

```
const treeData = [
  {
    title: "First Watchlists",
    key: "First Watchlists",
    children: [
      { title: " Open Data", key: "Open Data", checked: true },
      {
        title: "Department of trade ",
        key: "Department of trade ",
        checked: true
      },
      {
        title: "sanction List",
        key: "sanction List",
        checked: true
      },
      { title: "People's Daily", key: "People's Daily", checked: true },
      {
        title: "People  trades",
        key: "People trades",
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Second Watchlists",
    key: "Second Watchlists",
    children: [
      {
        title: "Second Service",
        key: "Second Service",
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Third Watchlists",
    key: "Third Watchlists",
    children: [
      {
        title: "National ",
        key: "National ",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        title: "Militants List",
        key: "Militants List",
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Forth Watchlists",
    key: "Forth Watchlists",
    children: [
      { title: "FAT", key: "FAT", checked: true },
      { title: "FAC", key: "FAC", checked: false },
      { title: "SC", key: "SC", checked: false },
      {
        title: "Data Council",
        key: "Data Council",
        checked: true
      },
      {
        title: " Sanctions List",
        key: "Sanctions List",
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  }
];

const Demo = () => {
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState(["0-0-0", "0-0-1"]);
  const [checkedKeys, setCheckedKeys] = useState(["0-0-0"]);
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);

  const onExpand = (expandedKeysValue) => {
    console.log("onExpand", expandedKeysValue); // if not set autoExpandParent to false, if children expanded, parent can not collapse.
    // or, you can remove all expanded children keys.

    setExpandedKeys(expandedKeysValue);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onCheck = (checkedKeysValue) => {
    console.log("onCheck", checkedKeysValue);
    setCheckedKeys(checkedKeysValue);
  };

  const onSelect = (selectedKeysValue, info) => {
    console.log("onSelect", info);
    setSelectedKeys(selectedKeysValue);
  };

  return (
    <Tree
      checkable
      onExpand={onExpand}
      expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
      autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
      onCheck={onCheck}
      checkedKeys={checkedKeys}
      onSelect={onSelect}
      selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
      treeData={treeData}
    />
  );
};
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd4168-forked-cgtz6?file=/index.js:155-2800)

Answer (score 0):

```
const buildCheckedKeys = () => {
  const checked = [];

  treeData.forEach((data) => {
    data.children.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.checked) {
        checked.push(item.key);
      }
    });
  });

  return checked;
};



const [checkedKeys, setCheckedKeys] = useState(buildCheckedKeys);
```

Code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd4168-forked-ey161?file=/index.js)